# Customize Matplotlib Colormap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I want to construct a colormap that mainly consists of three colors, similar to the colormap 'brg':
[image]

However, I'd like to modify it in two aspects:

1. I'd like to replace blue, red and green by blue, black and red, respectively.
2. I'd like to extend the area of the middle color. As a norm I am currently using matplotlibs 'Normalize', I guess I could choose a non linear normalization, but I'd rather just 'add red (black)' to the middle of the colormap and stick with the linear normalization.

Comment: Thanks JohanC, that did the trick. Go ahead and put it as an answer, so that I can mark it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to create such a colormap is via `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['b', 'k', 'k', 'r'])`. This divides the colors evenly, so pure black occupying 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of the range.

The function also allows to position the colors, via tuples of the form (`position`, `color`) with `position` ranging from `0` at the left (bottom) to `1` at the right (top). Below is an example where black occupies 10% of the range.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['b', 'k', 'k', 'r'])
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap1), orientation='horizontal',
             ticks=np.linspace(0,1,11), label='pure black occupies 1/3rd')
width = 0.1
cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', [(0, 'b'), ((1 - width) / 2, 'k'), ( (1 + width) / 2, 'k'), (1, 'r')])
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap2), orientation='horizontal',
             ticks=np.linspace(0,1,11), label=f'pure black occupies {width}')
plt.show()
```

[image: illustrative plot]